# Uncaught Error: near "(": syntax error when running apparently correct statement in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

The following syntax works perfectly in Postgresql:

```
SELECT
    rev_count.RevName,
    rev_count.MovTitle
FROM
    (SELECT
         rev.name as RevName,
         m.title as MovTitle,
         rat.stars as OrginalRat,
         rat.ratingDate as RatingDate,
         count(rat.stars) OVER (PARTITION BY rev.name, m.title) as RevCount,
         lead(rat.stars, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY rev.name, m.title ORDER BY rat.ratingDate) as NewRat
    FROM
        rating as rat
    LEFT JOIN
        reviewer as rev
    ON
        rat.rid = rev.rid
    LEFT JOIN
        movie as m
    ON
        rat.mid = m.mid) as rev_count
WHERE 
    rev_count.RevCount = 2
    AND rev_count.NewRat IS NOT NULL
    AND rev_count.NewRat > rev_count.OrginalRat
```

but I get the following error in SQLite:
 Uncaught Error: near "(": syntax error

any clues as to why that is? I suspect it has something to do with Aliasing but not sure exactly where the problem is.

Comment: in sqlite `OVER` doesn't exist https://www2.sqlite.org/lang_select.html

Comment: It will in the ~~upcoming~~ released earlier today 3.25 version, though. So be patient or come up with a way to do what you're trying to do without using window functions.

Comment: thank you both JérômeTeisseire and @Shawn

Answer (score 0):

Your query has a syntax error in general, so it will not work at all.
You can check the syntax here:
https://www.eversql.com/sql-syntax-check-validator/
`SQLite` does not support some features available in db engines like PostreSQL or mySQL. Please refer to the documentation for details.

Comment: Not helpful
I came here because I know I have an error, Jerome and Shawn shed some good light as to why the code doesn't work

Comment: you should mention you are aware you have a syntax error

Answer (score 0):

This query works just fine in SQLite 3.25.0.
(Earlier versions did not yet have window functions.)